# How to pass a mixture of string and variable into routerLink for navigation?

Tags: javascript, angular, transloco

I'm helping implement localization in an angular web application using a language switcher that I implemented using `transloco`. The way `transloco` works is that it adds the two digit language code `/en/` right after the domain in the URL, and the end point and sub location just follows after the language code. This was the old code that worked fine before I implemented localization:

```
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <ng-container *ngIf="sites$ | async as sites">
      <a [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" href="javascript:void(0);">{{ siteName$ | async }}</a>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button *ngIf="admin$ | async" mat-menu-item routerLink="admin">Admin</button>
        <button *ngFor="let site of sites" mat-menu-item [routerLink]="site.id">{{ site.name }}</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

So in order to go to the right page as soon as the app loads, I had to change "admin" to "en/admin" instead. However `site.id` is a variable, so how do I pass in the string value inside site.id inside the router link value. This is what I tried, but it obviously doesn't work properly:

```
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <ng-container *ngIf="sites$ | async as sites">
      <a [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" href="javascript:void(0);">{{ siteName$ | async }}</a>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button *ngIf="admin$ | async" mat-menu-item routerLink="en/admin">Admin</button>
        <button *ngFor="let site of sites" mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'en' + /site.id">{{ site.name }}</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Edit: Adding information
As you can see in the screenshot, when I tap on Site, it used to show Site before, but now it still displays Admin even though it navigates correctly. I tried what was recommended but it doesn't seem like it is fixing this issue
[image: Screenshot showing admin]

Comment: `[routerLink]="'en/' + site.id"` should do it. You were close, just the `/` needs to be part of the string, not the variable name. The square brackets cause the line to be read as javascript, that's why you need the single quotes around the string portion.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I updated the question, this solution doesn't seem to have fixed the issue

Comment: "when I tap on Site, it used to show Site before, but now it still displays Admin even though it navigates correctly." - I have no idea what this sentence means, could you explain a little more clearly? How about adding screenshots / descriptions of both what you expect, and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

[routerLink]="'en/'+site.id"

Comment: I updated the question, this solution doesn't seem to have fixed the issue